# MySQL DATE_FORMAT "%d" issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm sure there's a logic to this, but I do not understand it

```
date_format(date, '%m.%d.%Y') // Output: 03.05.2021
date_format(date, '%D.%m.%Y') // Output: 5th.03.2021
date_format(date, '%e.%m.%Y') // Output: 5.03.2021
```

But

```
date_format(date, '%d.%m.%Y') // Output: 28.02.2021
```

There seems to be an issue when I start the date_format with "%d", but I need my output to be 05.03.2021 (which is 5th March 2021), but I'm not able to achieve that. Can someone please explain this logic to me and help me?

Updated Explanation: In my database I have data from 5th March 2021 to 17th February 2021, so when I SELECT from the table using date_format(date_column, '%d.%m.%Y'), and order by date_column desc, the table begins from 28.02.2021 instead of 05.03.2021

Comment: Did you check what was actually in `date`. Because otherwise the www is about to crash from date confusion :)

Comment: Try `select date_format('2021-03-05', '%d.%m.%Y');` So you know which date you are actually formatting

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date which is stored as string to a valid mysql date ,yyyy-mm-dd , in the order by for example

```
SELECT *
from  table 
order by str_to_date(date_column,'%d.%m.%Y') desc
```

You could be clearer on how your data is stored by providing samples

Answer (score 0):

Your third example uses `%e`. Changing that to `%d` will give you the format you want.

If the value is stored in the database as a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, then ordering by that value will give you what you need:
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%d.%m.%Y') AS formatted_date FROM table ORDER BY date_column DESC`

N.B. Ordering by `formatted_date` won't give the order you want, because it's just a text string rather than a DATE or similar.

If the value is not stored in the database as a DATE or similar, then the suggestion from P.Salmon is what you want.